# Karma: Angular Module Mocking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am currently trying to write karma unit tests for a controller in an angular app.  For me the desired result is to load ONLY the controller which I am testing (assume for now I only ever want to test this one controller) and have all other dependencies mocked out for me.

To set the stage:

- I have a module: 'XYZ' defined in `js/xyz_module.js`
- I have a module: 'ABC' defined in `js/abc_module.js`
- module 'ABC' is dependent on 'XYZ'
- module 'ABC' has a controller: 'AbcController' defined in `js/abc_controller.js`
- my testing is to be done ONLY on 'AbcController'

**karma.conf.js:**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'js/abc_module.js',
        'js/controllers/abc_controller.js',
        'spec/karma/abc_controller_spec.js'
    ],
...
```

**abc_module.js:**

```
angular.module('ABC', ['XYZ']);
```

**abc_controller.js:**

```
angular.module('ABC').controller('AbcController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
}]);
```

**abc_controller_spec.js:**

```
describe('AbcController', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.mock.module('XYZ');
        module('ABC')
    });

    var $controller;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_
    }));

    describe('$scope.letters', function() {
        it("is set to three letters", function() {
            var $scope = {};
            $controller('AbcController', {$scope: $scope});
            expect($scope.letters.length).toEqual(3)
        })
    })
});
```

My theory was that, since module XYZ is a mocked module that I should NOT have to include `js/xyz_module.js` in my `karam.conf.js` file, but that the mocking framework would simply mock it for me.  Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case.  When I run karma I get an error that it cannot find the module 'XYZ'.  Is there any way around this?  If I have to include all dependencies even to test a portion of an application, it will make it exponentially more difficult with more complex applications.  Obviously this is a contrived example and the project I am actually working with involves many modules with many dependencies, making it exceedingly difficult to test portions of it if I have to effectively include the whole application.  I thought that was the whole point of mocking?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Couldn't fully understand the requirement. So you want to test only one controller at a time when karma runs instead of all the files?

Comment: I want to be able to test modules without having to include all the dependencies.  I would like to mock (perhaps stub is a better term) dependencies, particularly when the dependencies are not used in the code being tested.

Comment: `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('XYZ', []));`? Or maybe [this](http://southdesign.de/blog/mock-angular-js-modules-for-test-di.html#mock-module) is what you're looking for?

Comment: that sounds great, IF it worked!  Initially I was hoping that would do the trick but when I add: beforeEach(angular.mock.module('XYZ', [])); I still get the error: Failed to instantiate module XYZ due to: Module 'XYZ' is not available!

That sounds like it is trying to load an actual module, not a mock.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I think I now realise that angular.mock.module does not actually CREATE a module but is used to initialise an existing module.  As such, if I create an additional mock file with: `angular.module('XYZ',[]);`, add it to karma.conf.js and THEN do `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('XYZ'));` that seems to work.  One baby step forward.  The next step is mocking any dependencies that 'XYZ' has and that my 'ABC' module uses, but that is probably another question.